# Limit character strings in html input box to only state abbreviations

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, input

**Hello!**

I am coding a new HTML form that will collect upon many more items a state abbreviation (i.e. "ks"). Right now I have the -input field- limited so it only allows 2 characters. That doesn't keep visitors from entering something random into the field like "SS".

I am wanting a code that allows me to limit what can be placed in that field to only USA's official state abbreviations.

I am using HTML, CSS, and Javascript so far in my website. Thank you for all your help and ideas!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update.** Added all states, uppercase handling and jsfiddle link.

Here is a pure javascript implementation, should give you an idea of what you need to do:

```
<script>
    function validateState(el) {
    //put all states in this array. 
    var states =    ["AK","AL","AR","AS","AZ","CA","CO","CT","DC","DE",
"FL","GA","GU","HI","IA",
"ID","IL","IN","KS","KY","LA","MA","MD","ME","MH","MI","MN","MO","MS","MT",
"NC","ND","NE","NH","NJ","NM","NV","NY","OH","OK","OR","PA","PR","PW","RI",
"SC","SD","TN","TX","UT","VA","VI","VT","WA","WI","WV","WY"];
    for(var i=0;i< states.length;i++) {
      if(el.value.toUpperCase() == states[i]) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    //clear element if it doesn't match a state
    el.value = ""; //you could maybe do something else here.
    return false;
}
</script>
<input class="up" type="text" maxlength="2" onchange="validateState(this);"/>
```

See it working live here : http://jsfiddle.net/k7QQs/

Comment: You might want to add the css rule `{text-transform:uppercase}` to the input for in case someone enters "az" or check it like `el.value.toUpperCase()` in the function for the same reason. Because `"AZ" != "az"`.

Comment: Thanks @inhan updated. Seems the css transform doesn't actually change the text so I have to still do `toUpperCase()`

Comment: Thank you for your input! This actually provided me with exactly what I wanted! New thought though check out my new question below if you wish. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679838/alert-bar-rather-than-alert-box

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `<select>` html element.

```
<select>
  <option value="MA">MA<option>
  ....
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://www.bitconsultants.net/2008/jquery-u-s-states-autocomplete/) would help.

It has:

```
mustMatch:true,
```

Comment: Some example code would be nice... when that guy's site goes away, this answer won't help much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without a script:

```
<select name="state">
<option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
<option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
<option value="CA">California</option>
<option value="CO">Colorada</option>
<option value="CT">Conneticut</option>
<option value="DC">District of Colombia</option>
<option value="DE">Delaware</option>
<option value="FL">Florida</option>
<option value="FM">Federated States</option>
<option value="GA">Georgia</option>
<option value="GU">Guam</option>
<option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
<option value="IA">Iowa</option>
<option value="ID">Idaho</option>
<option value="IL">Illinois</option>
<option value="IN">Indiana</option>
<option value="KS">Kansas</option>
<option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
<option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
<option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
<option value="MD">Maryland</option>
<option value="ME">Maine</option>
<option value="MI">Michigan</option>
<option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
<option value="MO">Missouri</option>
<option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
<option value="MT">Montana</option>
<option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
<option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
<option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
<option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
<option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
<option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
<option value="NV">Nevada</option>
<option value="NY">New York</option>
<option value="OH">Ohio</option>
<option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
<option value="OR">Oregon</option>
<option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
<option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
<option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
<option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
<option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
<option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
<option value="TX">Texas</option>
<option value="UT">Utah</option>
<option value="VI">Virgin Islands</option>
<option value="VT">Vermont</option>
<option value="VA">Virginia</option>
<option value="WA">Washington</option>
<option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
<option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
<option value="WY">Wyoming</option>    
</select>
```

That method is easier on your users than expecting them to know a State abbreviation.

Or-

```
function validState(state){
    return state.toUpperCase() in{
        AL:1, AK:1, AZ:1,
        AR:1, CA:1, CO:1, CT:1,
        DE:1, DC:1, FL:1, GA:1,
        HI:1, ID:1, IL:1, IN:1, IA:1,
        KS:1, KY:1, LA:1, ME:1, MD:1,
        MA:1, MI:1,
        MN:1, MS:1, MO:1, MT:1, NE:1,
        NV:1, NH:1, NJ:1, NM:1,
        NY:1, NC:1, ND:1,
        OH:1, OK:1, OR:1, PA:1,
        RI:1, SC:1, SD:1, TN:1, TX:1,
        UT:1, VT:1, VA:1, WA:1,
        WV:1, WI:1, WY:1
    }
}
```