# Alert Bar rather than alert box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I now have a script that prevents users from entering anything but a state abbreviation in the state field of my form. Thanks to [gideon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368070/gideon)

I modified the script just a little to include an alert message when an invalid state is entered. But I don't really like it. I am going for an alert bar that flashes on the top of the page or maybe right below the field. Something that appears automatically when an incorrect abbreviation is entered and flash to grab the users attention and disappear after a few seconds. Any ideas or thoughts would be welcome! I am VERY open to suggestions! Thanks once again!

I am starting to think you guy's are not understanding me. This is the code I have:

```
<script>
                        function validateState(el) {
                        //put all states in this array. 
                        var states =    ["AK","AL","AR","AS","AZ","CA","CO","CT","DC","DE",
                    "FL","GA","GU","HI","IA",
                    "ID","IL","IN","KS","KY","LA","MA","MD","ME","MH","MI","MN","MO","MS","MT",
                    "NC","ND","NE","NH","NJ","NM","NV","NY","OH","OK","OR","PA","PR","PW","RI",
                    "SC","SD","TN","TX","UT","VA","VI","VT","WA","WI","WV","WY"];
                        for(var i=0;i< states.length;i++) {
                          if(el.value.toUpperCase() == states[i]) {
                            return true;
                          }
                        }
                        //clear element if it doesn't match a state
                        el.value = ""; //you could maybe do something else here.
                        alert('Invalid State Abbreviation, You must fix this before continuing')
                        document.getElementById("state").focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    </script>
```

I am wanting to have a bar run across the screen if the statement returns false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting @Shawn's code, you'll need a function to show the bar and hide the bar, I've removed the code that makes the bar blink:

```
function ShowError(txt)
{
  $("#bar").show();
  $("#bar").text(txt);
  $("#bar").animate({
      top: 0
  }, 1500);
}
function ClearError()
{
   $("#bar").hide();
}
```

Then later on you will just do:

```
if(el.value.toUpperCase() == states[i]) {
     ClearError();
     return true;
} else {
      ShowError("Please Enter a valid state");
}
```

See the whole code running here: http://jsfiddle.net/grFT7/8/

---

To make the bar disappear at some point you would do:

```
 setInterval(function () { $("#bar").hide(); }, 5000);
                           //hide the bar every 5 secs (5000 milliseconds).
```

Comment: Ok, so that made the entire thing work. Except I am seeing the red bar on page load and it is saying "Error" then when I type a fake state in it moves down and changes to "Please Enter a valid state" How do I hide it until the error happens?

Comment: You do this somewhere in a separate script tag on the top. `$(document).ready(function () {$("#bar").hide();});` Also, don't forget to [include jquery on the top of the page.](http://jquery.com/download/)

Comment: @MitchEvans whoops! I've updated the `ShowError()` method in my answer.

Comment: What about an image as the background rather than a color? I've tried everything I know and nothing is working.

Comment: Are you talking about the alert bar? Just add background image into the css for `#bar { ..}`

Comment: I did. It just turned transparent.

Comment: YAY! I got it to display my image! I now have a fancy notification box that displays the entered state is incorrect. Can we add a timer to it to disappear after a certain amount of time? If we can do this I will be happy! i PROMISE!

Comment: How can I use this alert bar script with other scripts such as an email validation script? Maybe something like a universal alert bar script.

Answer (score 3):

You can simple create an element that with be positioned above the view of the user (top: -100px etc). Once an invalid state has been entered you can use a Library like jQuery to animate it to top position 0. You can make it flash with a simple conditional statement inside of a setInterval();

I'm not sure if you are wanting to use jQuery but if you do then your code would look something like this:

```
//if the input is not what you expect..
if(input != state){
    //drop the bar down
    $("#bar").animate({
            top: 0
    }, 1500);//drop it in 1500 milliseconds.
    //this is a lot like a loop that runs every 400 milliseconds.. 
    setInterval(function () {  <-------------------------------| 
        if ($("#bar").css("display") == 'none') {              |
            //if the bar is HIDDEN show it..                   |
            $("#bar").show();                                  |  
        } else {                                               | 
            //else hide it.                                    | 
            $("#bar").hide();                                  |
        }                                                      |
    }, 400);//<< EVERY 400 milli-seconds go here >-------------^
}
```

Of course this is just an example and can easily be translated back to traditional JavaScript.

Check out the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grFT7/).

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok, I am not understanding exactly how to make this work. Can you explain further?

Comment: I added some comments into your code. Hope thats ok @Shawn :)

Comment: @MitchEvans I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [BootStrap's Alert](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#alerts). It is easy to use and looks cool.